# Header pivot in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, header

I am building a report that needs to build a dynamic header from a query.

If for example, the query returns this result:

[image]

The header should look like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In other queries there may be more records between 3 and 45.

Comment: The last 5 records are always the same.

Comment: Do you mean the last 5 for each ProductCode are always `45 = EE`, `46 = First` etc.?

Comment: Yes it is. Except for the last column that takes the ProductCode from the records above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a work around for this.

In your tablix:

- Select the ProductCode as the Row Group
- Select the Code as column group
- For the values select First(Element)
- In the column header you need to add an expression: If(Code >= 45,"",Code)
- You should also use the above IF statement to customize the borders (don't show bottom border if code >=45)

This will give you something fairly similar to what you need. The only issue is that since the cells are not merged (for the codes >=45) the values won't be aligned vertically in the center.